# PHP - Get all images from class with simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to get all images from the info box in Wikipedia page. I made this code but it gets all images from the page not only for the info box ,i need some help.

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$wikilink = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberdeen_F.C.";

//Wikipedia page to parse
    $html = file_get_html($wikilink);


    $images_array = array();

    foreach ($html->find('table.infobox vcard td, img') as $element) {
        $allimages = strtok($element->src . '|', '|');
        array_push($images_array, $allimages);
    }
print_r($images_array);
```

The below example shows the html elements what i want to get[image: The above example shows the html elements what i want to get]

Comment: `it didnt work` __how__? Your laptop explodes? You get blank page? Aliens invade your room?

Comment: haha aliens maybe . When i run the code i get all images from the page not only those of the info box.

Comment: Because you have `,` in your selector?

Comment: i have removed the `,` i get empty array.